# alternate odd even css style to nested unordered list

Tags: javascript, css

I have a multi level nested unordered list. I was trying to display the list as an alternate row with odd even css style. But I am not getting what I want. Here is what I have tried so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8WkUx3BJKnwlIH6bztLe?p=preview

What I wanted to make it is like the following. If its possible to achieve only using css then that would be great for me.

[image]

```css
ul {
 padding-left: 30px;
 list-style: none;
}

#main > ul {
 padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
 padding: 5px;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
 background:#f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>three one</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>six</li>
          <li>eight</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because of the unpredictable relationship between the lengths of the parent and child lists, some scripting is probably required for this.

Comment: Yeah...JS absolutely is the way to go.

Comment: My project is based on angularjs. And I am using  angular directive recursively to achieve this multi level list.

Comment: That's information worth sharing in your question.