# CSS: alternating list with odd even with non-repeating color in child list

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<li>ho</li>
<ul>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
  <li>ho</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
li {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  background: blue;
  width: 1000px;
  height: inherit;
}


li:nth-child(odd), li:nth-child(odd):before {
     background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(odd)::before {
     background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color:white;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3TuN/1303/), so you can see what it looks like. As you see I want an alternating list but also for the child-ul to never repeat the same color. As you see there are two green lines following each other. How can I prevent that?

Any idea or trick to achieve that?

Comment: FYI you shouldn't be nesting a UL within a UL like that

Comment: Not possible with CSS as such (although you could hack it manually). You need JS - Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487297/alternate-odd-even-css-style-to-nested-unordered-list#comment60583939_36487297

Comment: Yes your nested `ul` must be inside one of your `li`'s.

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/K3TuN/1306/

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

I reversed the color settings for every `li` wich is nested inside two `ul`.

So every li wich is inside of two uls will get a green background and a white font color. If its odd it will be colored blue.

```css
ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
li {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
}
ul ul li {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}


li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  background: blue;
  width: 1000px;
  height: inherit;
}

ul ul li:before {
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(odd), li:nth-child(odd):before {
     background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(odd)::before {
     background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color:white;
}

ul ul li:nth-child(odd), ul ul li:nth-child(odd):before {
     background-color: blue;
}
ul ul li:nth-child(odd)::before {
     background-color: blue;
}
ul ul li:nth-child(even) {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho
    <ul>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can't deny it seems to work but explaining the logic would be very helpful

Comment: That works until you add another li then your logic breaks

Comment: Removing one "ho" list item before the nested list breaks it as well. However, that's just due to missing CSS styles. The idea behind this is to set alternating start/default background colours depending on the nesting level and the odd/even class of the nested list's parent.

Comment: Yes, how would that work if the number of "<li>"s is dynamic and varying?

Comment: I suspected as much...it's brittle. JS is the optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

@Robert's answer doesn't quite work. You need to use multiple nested `:nth-child()`'s to accomodate all of the possible combinations:

```css
hr {
  margin: 60px 0;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
li {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  background: blue;
  width: 1000px;
  height: inherit;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
    color:white;
}


li:nth-child(odd), li:nth-child(odd):before {
     background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(odd)::before {
     background-color: green;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color:white;
}

/* parent is green so set odd blue */
li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(odd){
     background-color: blue;
     color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(odd)::before {
     background-color: blue;
}

/* parent is green so even to green */
li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even){
     background-color: green;
     color: #000;
}
li:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even)::before {
     background-color: green;
}

/* correct the text colour for nested elements */
li:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(odd){
     color: #000;
}
li:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(even){
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho
    <ul>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho
    <ul>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
      <li>ho</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.

Comment: Try to add more first level list items after the one containing the nested list. This will break it depending on the number of nested list items being even or odd.

Comment: That's actually nothing to do with my code. It is because of the absolutely positioned elements in OP's code. The logic still works. OP has issues with collapsing elements which is out of the scope of this question.